# Email notifier supporting Gmail as of 2023

Tags: email, notification, gmail

I often see incoming emails too late, when they needed urgent reply.

I am not always in front of my computer, therefore I need a software that pops up a notification whenever I receive an email, and keeps this notification visible until I manually dismiss it. It needs to be supporting Gmail as email provider, through IMAP protocol.

I used an old small software called Spiffy but it is not working any more.

I am astonished I didn't find plenty of standalone softwares like this. I found many mail notifiers, but all of them are very old and don't work any more, or don't support Gmail any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Pop Peeper](https://www.esumsoft.com/pop-peeper/) which does support Gmail via OATH2 and app password configuration in Gmail. The latter is considered a "security risk" accompanied by a recommendation for a strong password.

From the linked site:

Email Notification Options

- Sound notifications: single sound for any new mail, or a customized sound for each account
- Tray icon notification that display the color and number of new
  messages for each account
- Flashing scroll-lock or num-lock LED
- Windows popup indicating which account(s) received new email
- BalloonTip displays the subject and sender of the last email message
  received
- Automatically open POP Peeper or launch your email client when new
  email is received

It's a free program, although some features become available when a payment is made.

Comment: I see that Chime plugin for Pop Peeper adds a sound notification, and that you can set a repeating sound. I will check it out.